# How can I clear cache memory in Android?

Tags: android

I want to clear cache memory when I close my application in Android.  A code example would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "clear cache memory"? The operating system will reclaim the memory used by your application when the application exits. Is there something else you want to clear, like files on disk?

Comment: pretty sure he means the application cache directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should do the trick, although this example has no error handling you will want to add that.

```
   public void clearCache() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Clearing Cache.");
    File[] dir = mContext.getCacheDir().listFiles();
    if(dir != null){
        for (File f : dir){
            f.delete();
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: @Hi schwiz,i am fresher in android,so can u tell where can i use this method in application

Comment: you can call getChacheDir anywhere that you have a reference to the application context, usually in an Activity or a Service.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cann't really close your application since Android takes care about the process lifetimes.

And if you're talking about RAM there is also no need to free unused memory because Android manages the memory as well.

Comment: He is talking about the cache on the system disk that things like using a webview leave behind.